# TWebBrowser and URL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, twebbrowser

I'm working on a software to verify the problem of porting it from **D5** to **XE5**. In **D5**, `TWebBrowser.BeforeNavigate2` was call each time the user click on the submit button of a displayed form. In XE5, it's not the case. I figured out it is because the URL for the submit contain `http:/aDirectory/ExecToBeCall.exe`. If I add an extra / after: the event is fire.

Under D5 the URL is change for:

`http ://localhost/aDirectory/ExecToBeCall.exe`  (space added to break the link in the post)

That behavior of `TWebBrowser` under **D5** to fire anyway and change the URL is important for the software and I cannot change the **HTML** (about 2000 files) to contain 2. It allowed us to know if the submit was made inside Delphi or from a outside Browser. I tried other and newer events of `TWebBrowser` and none are fire.

How can I be informed of a problematic URL, check it and change it into a localhost URL? A small and clean method would be preferable.

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`TWebBrowser` is just a thin wrapper around Internet Explorer's ActiveX object, so it is IE itself, not `TWebBrowser`, that is behaving differently.

`http:/aDirectory/ExecToBeCall.exe` is actually a valid URL. Since the `:` is not followed by `//`, there is no authority portion in the URL, and thus no explicit hostname.  `localhost` is used as an implicit hostname, and the path is `/aDirectory/ExecToBeCall.exe`. That is what the URL is being changed to in D5, which is correct behavior.  Changing the URL to `http://aDirectory/ExecToBeCall.exe` is incorrect, as that creates an authority portion of the URL and thus the hostname is explicitly set to `aDirectory` and the path is set to `/ExecToBeCall.exe`, which is not what you want.

Why the URL is not changing in XE5, I have no clue. Sounds like a bug in whatever version of IE is being used in that version of `TWebBrowser`.

In any case, it is IE that is triggering the event, so if it is not triggering for a URL it does not like, there is nothing you can do about that, short of using the browser's DOM interfaces to handle the `onsubmit` event of the HTML webform directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's seem after all that the problem come from some preprocessing of the file that we do. Which I was unaware of at the time of my post. Apparently one / stop working around IE 6 or 7 from what I'm told.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect unexpected url instead of navigating to it, you can start with TEmbeddedWB project or you can DIY by extending `TWebBrowser` class with `IDocHostUIHandler`, which has an interesting method `TranslateURL`.

```
function TAdvWebBrowser.TranslateURL(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POLESTR; var ppchURLOut: POLESTR): HRESULT;
var
  Url: string;
  BufferSize: Integer;
begin
  Url := PChar(pchURLIn);
  if GetSafeUrlFor(Url) then
  begin
    ppchURLOut := CoTaskMemAlloc(BufferSize);
    CopyMemory(ppchURLOut, PChar(Url), BufferSize);

    // redirects to new location
    Result := S_OK; 
  end
  else
    // no redirection
    Result := S_FALSE;
end;

// You can change the function to add more complex redirection rules
function GetSafeUrlFor(var Url: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Url.EndsWithText('.exe');
  if Result then
    Url := 'http://localhost/';
end;
```